# 15.04 sound is muted and will not unmute

Tags: sound

I upgraded to 15.04 and the sound is muted. How can I unmute it? I have tried going to the sound controller with no success. the sound icon by the clock will not unmute.

Answer (score 0):

Open up `alsamixer` by entering it into the terminal.

Check to see if Auto-Mute is enabled:

[image]

If it is, navigate to 'Auto-Mute Mode' with the right arrow key.

Set 'Auto-Mute Mode' to 'Disabled' with the down arrow key.

[image]

[Source](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/10/fix-no-sound-turn-off-auto-mute-in.html)

Comment: I followed the above directions but the program is still muted. I noted that when I went to alsamixer and tried to increase the volume to my speakers, the volume automatically decreased to nothing.

Comment: @user459353 what speakers are you using?

Comment: I'm using Logitech headphones